# problem when using rotation of xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, data-analysis

I have a "Type Error: int object is not callable" when I try to run this code on jupyter notebook , the previous steps to this code are as follows:
1- I have imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt along with pandas as pd
2- defined x as a series of string data type
3- defined y as numeric data type
the code is as follows:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))

x = data_used_cars["Brand"]
y = data_used_cars["Cars Listings"]

plt.bar(x=x, height=y)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Data set:

| Brand | Cars Listings |
| --- | --- |
| Audi | 419 |
| BMW | 636 |
| Mercedes-Benz | 820 |
| Mitsubishi | 306 |
| Renault | 438 |
| Toyota | 509 |
| Volkswagen | 875 |

hope I can find a solution to this

Comment: The code is called correctly. What are the contents in the `x` and `y` variables? I assume the issue is there somewhere.

Comment: x is a string data type while y is an "int64" , x represents car types and y is the frequency , this problem caused me a headache , I cant figure out the cause

Comment: I attached an image showing the dataset used

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading the matplotlib Library to version 3.5.1 fixed the problem**